# Regex: How to get full file name with special character

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have the following pattern

```
"\w+\.(js|css|less|html|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|xml)$"
```

to match a part of url.

When I am testing with the example **"menu/abc-brand-dark-theme.svg"**, the full match is only **"theme.svg"**. My goal is to get the full filename **"abc-brand-dark-theme.svg".**

How can I modify my regex to match?

Comment: Hyphen is not part of `\w`. You should write either `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+` and use `[\w-]+\.(js|css|less|html|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|xml)$` or even better `\w+(?:-\w+)*\.(js|css|less|html|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|xml)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match more characters that just `\w`, `.+` might even be a good fit or `[\w-]+` as in the comments